# How can I offset the start of a fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

How should I offset the start of a blender fluid simulation? I have a short video with different cameras at different points, and I only want 1 fluid simulation at a time. Adjusting the start / stop times did not help, and the fluid simulation type cannot be keyframed. How should I get about to doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the offset field in the domain's settings:

[image: Offset image]

What you would normally want is a negative offset. For example, if the camera switches at frame #240 (10 seconds at 24fps), the offset should be -240. Blender will skip the first 240 frames. It only starts doing the simulation at frame 240.

Here is an example of an offset at frame 350 (60fps):

Frame #349:
[image: Frame #349]

Frame #350
[image: Frame #350]