# Fluid animation timings

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I want to make a short animation, of which one part is a drop falling and hitting a surface. Now I want the animation to begin at 300th frame and since I am using the default 24 fps, the start is at 300/24=12.5 seconds. However on changing the Start parameter under the domain settings to 12.5 and end to 15, on baking the simulation simply doesn't seem to happen. But on using the default the animation works perfectly. It's taking the same amount of time and cache memory to bake both the times, so I am guessing the simulation IS happening but somewhere wrong place on the timeline.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49873/how-can-i-offset-the-start-of-a-fluid-simulation

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the animation to start at the 300th frame, you'll need to set Frame Start to 300, not 12.5.  It seems that what you're doing right now is running an animation for only two and a half frames, so it's so fast that you can't even see it.